# Introductory reference on the damped wave equation

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

Where can I find an introductory reference book (or lecture notes) on the classical theory for the damped wave equation?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Evans text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821849743) on Partial Differential Equations has some material on damped wave equation, albeit not sure if I would say it is introductory. However, these [lecture notes](http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-PDE%20pt4.pdf) could be helpful potentially.

Comment: Second link is unfortunately broken.